# Are abs muscles able to grow?

Tags: exercise, gym, bodyweight-exercises

So, my full gym experience is around 2 years (counted only periods without long breaks, first time visited gym at the end of 2013 etc). Last 1.5 year only once I was skipping for 1.5 month because of eye trauma.

Anyway, i always was wanted to have good abs. Still I'm on my way to it.

So this is year 2014
[image]

This previous year 2016 summer
[image]

This is today
[image]

There is a big difference between first an the other pics. But no difference between 2 and 3.

I do crunches with dumbells, leg raises to the bar, cable crunches. Tried different way.
 Like 4 times per 20 w lightweight, or like 3 times 15 heavy etc.

And the weight is grown a little, btw (since last year). But the way how abd looks like - no.

And not so long ago i met one guy at the gym who said that abs exercises are not working and abs can't grow at all, it's all about fat + genetics.

So is he right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.

Abs are a muscle and behave the same way every other muscle in the body does when you use a resistive load to work it consistently; they grow.

Genetics *can* affect posture which changes how abs appear in the mirror.

The saying is still correct: "Abs are **grown** in the gym and **revealed** in the kitchen."

Comment: Interesting. But how they grow then? I mean, it's barely visible in mirror or what?

Comment: Because of afaik there are some bodybuilders who look shreddered but at the same time their abs not looking good

Comment: Bull Mentula is a good example

Comment: wellp, I think no better answer would appear. still got no gains in abs btw

Comment: FYI you have good abs now, you need to work on your chest and shoulders more from those photos. Get them big traps.

Comment: Wellp, I got shoulders trauma or shmt, feel pain on even incline bench press