# Excercise to avoid Back Pain after crunches

Tags: exercise, muscle, back-pain, lower-back

There are number of articles saying some hip flexors inflexibility cause stress on spine and hence cause pain in lower back due to crunches or leg lift or even squats.
What can i do as exercise which will prevent my back from injury due to performance of these exercise? please suggest safe exercise  which wont need an expert to do correctly.

As i understand hip flexor and extensor weakness is responsible for Psoas major activation, but to strengthen flexor extensor more pressure will come on Psoas.
It is becoming a catch39 situation.

[Reference](http://www.exrx.net/Kinesiology/Inflexibilities.html#HipFlexor)

Comment: I'm unsure what you're asking.  You ask for "exercise which will prevent my back from injury due to crunches", and also request suggestions of exercises "for leg extensor and flexor...".  What do you want?

Comment: @ChristianConti-Vock edited

Comment: If you got pain in back after crunches then you probably doing crunches wrong. Try to fix technique or, maybe its the other reason - then try do different exercise for your abs, for instance, ab pulldowns (my favorite one, you can check out my progress here https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/35847/are-abs-muscles-able-to-grow and its ab exercie I been doing 80% of my gym-life. And 20% is leg raises to the bar)

Comment: I'm sorry, I still don't understand your request.  Why do you do crunches?  Perhaps I will be able to help you if I understand your motivation for doing crunches.

Comment: @ChristianConti-Vock edited question further, its not only about crunches bur any movement which involve hip flexion. To be honest I stopped doing crunches after getting pain and my back pain also vanished, now i usually do leg raises with weight and my back pain has again surfaced.

Comment: Your cessation of specific "ab" work and the subsequent reduction of back pain remind me of ["Abs"](https://startingstrength.com/article/abs).  Instead focusing on particular muscles or small groups of them (for example, rectus abdominus, psoas major, hip flexors), consider compound movements (such as the squat) that train your muscles in greater groups.  By the way, squats train hip _extensors_; hip flexors, not so much.

Answer (score 2):

I'd highly recommend rethinking your core training.

Sit-ups cause dangerously high compression and shearing forces to your spine about 730 pounds (3300 N) which well exceed safe levels established by the CDC.

[image]Combine that with a tight Iliopsoas which attaches to the side of your vertebral column - put simply that's a POWERFUL muscle in that's pulling your entire spinal column and pelvis out of alignment.

Stretch your hip flexors (IP) and hamstrings.  Strengthen your glutes and innercore.  Stay away from anything that isn't a static hold (such as planks) for your abs.  Otherwise you're on a path that will likely lead to Chronic Lowerback Pain and IV disc issues.

---

*Source:* https://www.cdc.gov/niosh/index.htm